# Computing a function over a series for a new value in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I have an extremely complex and long function in PineScript for a time series that represent exactly what I want to measure. That's great, isn't it? Well, not exactly. The problem I face is that I would like to know what would be the value of that function considering a predicted value in the series. I mean, just considering the same time series as it is, and that new value.

For the sake of the example, I have extremely simplified below the function "myfun", that you can pass as source, the time series such as close values, high, low, or any other predefined or created with time series...

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test Array")

myfun(source,length) =>
    ta.cci(source,length)

plot(myfun(close,20), title='myfun function',color=color.red)
```

So, in the reduced example above, instead of computing the "cci" value over the time series "close", I would like to compute the same, but assuming a shift if the series where the last value is set manually. It effectively compute/predict the cci if the next value is... let's say 4.

```
recreateSourceWithNewValue(source,new_value) =>
   Do whatever it has to be done to return a time series where source is shifted and new_value is the the last one.
```

so I could just use...

```
plot(myfun(recreateSourceWithNewValue(close,4),20), title='myfun function',color=color.red)
```

and see how a new value "4" would behave though my function.

From what I have seen, it is possible to reference previous positions of the time series with the [] operator, but it doesn't accept negative values that would mean somehow the kind of shifting that I would like to get. And in addition I have not found any simple way to redefine these series.

I have seen the existence of arrays in the language, and I guess it is feasible to recreate the behaviour of the function with arrays, though from the small tests I have performed, it generates too many inconsistencies and it would require to perform extensive tests over each of the recreated internal functions... so I'm wondering if someone may know a way to recreate the time series with the new value though any function I have not found in the manual...

Thanks in advance...

:-)